# Insert a number of spaces in replacement

Tags: regex, vim

I have a long line of code that I need to split into separate lines:

```
Method(new Namespace::ClassName(LongParameterName1, LongParameterName1, LongParameterName3));
```

I want to split it the following way:

```
Method(new Namespace::ClassName(LongParameterName1,
                                LongParameterName1,
                                LongParameterName3));
```

The regular expression will be like this:

```
s:, :,\r                         :
```

How can I set a number of spaces that are used (if I can)?

**NOTE:** I have quite a big number of lines like this so that's why I want to use the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the position where you want to begin variable names in following lines and use a substitution command with expression, like:

```
:let c = strridx(getline('.'), '(')
:s/\v(,)/\=submatch(1) . "\r" . printf("%" . c . "s", " ")/g
```

I wrote them in two instructions to avoid a Markdown scroll, but you can join them with a pipe character.

First instruction searches the position of the last opening parentheses (the first one beginning from the end). And second instruction uses a `printf()` to insert that number of spaces after the newline character.

It yields:

```
Method(new Namespace::ClassName(LongParameterName1,
                                LongParameterName1,
                                LongParameterName3));
```

To repeat this task multiple times you can wrap these instructions in a function and call them from a `:g` command. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: It depends what you mean with **native**. As far as I know, to do an operation in the replacement part you have to evaluate it. And it's a feature implemented in most used regular expression engines.

Answer (score 1):

That how I would do it:

- set a macro (`qa`') that search for the next ',' (`<escape>\,`), hop into edit mode and hit enter (`i<enter>`), quit recording the macro (`q`)
- replay that macro very quickly until I'm done with the line (`@a` then `@@`)
- replace the cursor on the second line and start recording a new macro (`qa`'): `I` then press `<space>` until your parameter is sufficiently tabbed, and move to next line while replacing the cursor on the first caracter (`<escape>j^`), quit recording the macro (`q`)
- and replay that final macro like the first one (`@a` then `@@`)

That looks less elegant than regexes, but IMHO, when it's time to get things done, well, it's time to get things done :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the regex first and then indent. For instance...

```
s:, :,\r:g
V?Method<cr><cr>8>
```

In real practice I'd probably use `>.......` instead of `8>` because it lets you visualize how much you're indenting.